# ubuntu 22.04 (92)Protocol not available: AH00076: Failed to enable APR_TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT

Tags: apache2, rstudio

I am new to Ubuntu. I have windows 10 installed and UBUNTU22.04 version on my computer. I want to install opencpu and when I write this code "sudo apachectl restart" on Ubuntu I receive this error:

```
httpd not running, trying to start
[Fri Sep 23 13:58:31.764604 2022] [core:warn] [pid 88] (92)Protocol not available: AH00076: Failed to enable APR_TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT
[Fri Sep 23 13:58:31.764848 2022] [core:warn] [pid 88] (92)Protocol not available: AH00076: Failed to enable APR_TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT
[Fri Sep 23 13:58:31.764858 2022] [core:warn] [pid 88] (92)Protocol not available: AH00076: Failed to enable APR_TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT
```

I was wondering how can I solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to the end of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none
```

Then run `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Answer (score 0):

WSL 1 doesn't support `TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT` socket option:

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1953

You have to disable it:

```
AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36469527/installing-apache-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux